# Download XML document from a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose I have some `XElement element` (I can load it from the database). I need place a Link on the page so after clicking on it user can download an XML document created from `element.ToString()`.
I wouldn't like to save this doc to a file before user clicks on this link.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could save the XML on the server before returning it to the client:

```
string file = Server.MapPath("~/somefolder/somefile.xml");
File.WriteAllText(file, element.ToString());
```

Comment: Please, read the question carefully - "I **wouldn't like** to save this doc to a file before user clicks on this link". That is the question.

Comment: No, this will happen in the controller action that is invoked once the user clicks on the link.